# Android OnEditorActionListener() actionId give 0 when I click Done key

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have created one keyboard.When user enter numbers , its entering particular EditText.But When User click on `Done` key, it didn't go to `setOnEditorActionListener` but its closing the keyboard.

This is my code :

```
 final EditText txtQty = new EditText(this);
        txtQty.setHeight(1);
        txtQty.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 42));
        txtQty.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
        txtQty.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
        txtQty.setSelectAllOnFocus(true);
        txtQty.setTextSize(9);
        txtQty.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        txtQty.setHint("0.0");
        txtQty.setHighlightColor(R.color.green);
        tr.addView(txtQty);
 txtQty.setOnEditorActionListener( new OnEditorActionListener() {
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                Log.i("KeyBoard" ,"Inside the Edit Text");
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE ||actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT ) { ......}
```

Here its give actionId = 0
and EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT =5

When I run through the Android Softkeyboard its working fine

```
 txtQty.setOnEditorActionListener( new OnEditorActionListener() {
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                Log.i("KeyBoard" ,"Inside the Edit Text");
                Log.i("---EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT---" , EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
                Log.i("---actionId---" , actionId);
                Log.i("---event---" , event);
                Log.i("---EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE---" , EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
```

Here giving `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT =5 , actionId =5 & EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE = 6, actionId=6`
But when I run through my Soft keyboard gave  `EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT =5 , actionId =0 & EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE = 6, actionId=0`

This is the problem.Where its wrong? Why it didn't take `actionId` value?

This is kind of scenario i am doing:

[image]

**EDITED/UPDATED**

```
    public class SoftKeyboard extends InputMethodService implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener {
    static final boolean DEBUG = false;
    static final boolean PROCESS_HARD_KEYS = true;
    private KeyboardView mInputView;
    private CandidateView mCandidateView;
    private CompletionInfo[] mCompletions;
    private StringBuilder mComposing = new StringBuilder();
    private boolean mPredictionOn;
    private boolean mCompletionOn;
    private int mLastDisplayWidth;
    private boolean mCapsLock;
    private long mLastShiftTime;
    private long mMetaState;
    private LatinKeyboard mSymbolsKeyboard;
    private LatinKeyboard mSymbolsShiftedKeyboard;
    private LatinKeyboard mQwertyKeyboard;
    private LatinKeyboard mCurKeyboard; 
    private String mWordSeparators;

    @Override public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mWordSeparators = getResources().getString(R.string.word_separators);
    }

    @Override public void onInitializeInterface() {
        if (mQwertyKeyboard != null) {
            int displayWidth = getMaxWidth();
            if (displayWidth == mLastDisplayWidth) return;
            mLastDisplayWidth = displayWidth;
        }
        mQwertyKeyboard = new LatinKeyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty);
        mSymbolsKeyboard = new LatinKeyboard(this, R.xml.symbols);
        mSymbolsShiftedKeyboard = new LatinKeyboard(this, R.xml.symbols_shift);
    }


    @Override public View onCreateInputView() {
        mInputView = (KeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.input, null);
        mInputView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
        mInputView.setKeyboard(mQwertyKeyboard);
        return mInputView;
    }

    @Override public View onCreateCandidatesView() {
        mCandidateView = new CandidateView(this);
        mCandidateView.setService(this);
        return mCandidateView;
    }

    @Override public void onStartInput(EditorInfo attribute, boolean restarting) {
        super.onStartInput(attribute, restarting);

        mComposing.setLength(0);
        updateCandidates();

        if (!restarting) {
            mMetaState = 0;
        }

        mPredictionOn = false;
        mCompletionOn = false;
        mCompletions = null;

        switch (attribute.inputType&EditorInfo.TYPE_MASK_CLASS) {
            case EditorInfo.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER:
            case EditorInfo.TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME:
                mCurKeyboard = mSymbolsKeyboard;
                break;

            case EditorInfo.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE:
                mCurKeyboard = mSymbolsKeyboard;
                break;

            case EditorInfo.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT:
                mCurKeyboard = mQwertyKeyboard;
                mPredictionOn = true;
                int variation = attribute.inputType &  EditorInfo.TYPE_MASK_VARIATION;
                if (variation == EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD ||
                        variation == EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD) {
                    mPredictionOn = false;
                }

                if (variation == EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS 
                        || variation == EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_URI
                        || variation == EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_FILTER) {
                    mPredictionOn = false;
                }

                if ((attribute.inputType&EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_COMPLETE) != 0) {

                    mPredictionOn = false;
                    mCompletionOn = isFullscreenMode();
                }

                updateShiftKeyState(attribute);
                break;

            default:
                mCurKeyboard = mQwertyKeyboard;
                updateShiftKeyState(attribute);
        }
        mCurKeyboard.setImeOptions(getResources(), attribute.imeOptions);
    }

    @Override public void onFinishInput() {
        super.onFinishInput();

        // Clear current composing text and candidates.
        mComposing.setLength(0);
        updateCandidates();
        setCandidatesViewShown(false);

        mCurKeyboard = mQwertyKeyboard;
        if (mInputView != null) {
            mInputView.closing();
        }
    }

    @Override public void onStartInputView(EditorInfo attribute, boolean restarting) {
        super.onStartInputView(attribute, restarting);
        mInputView.setKeyboard(mCurKeyboard);
        mInputView.closing();
    }

    @Override 
    public void onUpdateSelection(int oldSelStart, int oldSelEnd,
            int newSelStart, int newSelEnd,
            int candidatesStart, int candidatesEnd) {
        super.onUpdateSelection(oldSelStart, oldSelEnd, newSelStart, newSelEnd,
                candidatesStart, candidatesEnd);
        if (mComposing.length() > 0 && (newSelStart != candidatesEnd
                || newSelEnd != candidatesEnd)) {
            mComposing.setLength(0);
            updateCandidates();
            InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
            if (ic != null) {
                ic.finishComposingText();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override 
    public void onDisplayCompletions(CompletionInfo[] completions) {
        if (mCompletionOn) {
            mCompletions = completions;
            if (completions == null) {
                setSuggestions(null, false, false);
                return;
            }

            List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i=0; i<(completions != null ? completions.length : 0); i++) {
                CompletionInfo ci = completions[i];
                if (ci != null) stringList.add(ci.getText().toString());
            }
            setSuggestions(stringList, true, true);
        }
    }

    private boolean translateKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        mMetaState = MetaKeyKeyListener.handleKeyDown(mMetaState,
                keyCode, event);
        int c = event.getUnicodeChar(MetaKeyKeyListener.getMetaState(mMetaState));
        mMetaState = MetaKeyKeyListener.adjustMetaAfterKeypress(mMetaState);
        InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
        if (c == 0 || ic == null) {
            return false;
        }

        boolean dead = false;

        if ((c & KeyCharacterMap.COMBINING_ACCENT) != 0) {
            dead = true;
            c = c & KeyCharacterMap.COMBINING_ACCENT_MASK;
        }

        if (mComposing.length() > 0) {
            char accent = mComposing.charAt(mComposing.length() -1 );
            int composed = KeyEvent.getDeadChar(accent, c);

            if (composed != 0) {
                c = composed;
                mComposing.setLength(mComposing.length()-1);
            }
        }

        onKey(c, null);

        return true;
    }


    @Override 
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (event.getRepeatCount() == 0 && mInputView != null) {
                    if (mInputView.handleBack()) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                break;

            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL:
                if (mComposing.length() > 0) {
                    onKey(Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE, null);
                    return true;
                }
                break;

            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                return false;



            default:
                if (PROCESS_HARD_KEYS) {
                    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE
                            && (event.getMetaState()&KeyEvent.META_ALT_ON) != 0) {
                        InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
                        if (ic != null) {
                            ic.clearMetaKeyStates(KeyEvent.META_ALT_ON);
                            keyDownUp(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A);
                            keyDownUp(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_N);
                            keyDownUp(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_D);
                            keyDownUp(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_R);
                            keyDownUp(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_O);
                            keyDownUp(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_I);
                            keyDownUp(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_D);
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (mPredictionOn && translateKeyDown(keyCode, event)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override 
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (PROCESS_HARD_KEYS) {
            if (mPredictionOn) {
                mMetaState = MetaKeyKeyListener.handleKeyUp(mMetaState,
                        keyCode, event);
            }
        }

        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }

    private void commitTyped(InputConnection inputConnection) {
        if (mComposing.length() > 0) {
            inputConnection.commitText(mComposing, mComposing.length());
            mComposing.setLength(0);
            updateCandidates();
        }
    }

    private void updateShiftKeyState(EditorInfo attr) {
        if (attr != null 
                && mInputView != null && mQwertyKeyboard == mInputView.getKeyboard()) {
            int caps = 0;
            EditorInfo ei = getCurrentInputEditorInfo();
            if (ei != null && ei.inputType != EditorInfo.TYPE_NULL) {
                caps = getCurrentInputConnection().getCursorCapsMode(attr.inputType);
            }
            mInputView.setShifted(mCapsLock || caps != 0);
        }
    }

    private boolean isAlphabet(int code) {
        if (Character.isLetter(code)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void keyDownUp(int keyEventCode) {
        getCurrentInputConnection().sendKeyEvent(
                new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, keyEventCode));
        getCurrentInputConnection().sendKeyEvent(
                new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, keyEventCode));
    }

    private void sendKey(int keyCode) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case '\n':
                keyDownUp(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);
                break;
            default:
                if (keyCode >= '0' && keyCode <= '9') {
                    keyDownUp(keyCode - '0' + KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0);
                } else {
                    getCurrentInputConnection().commitText(String.valueOf((char) keyCode), 1);
                }
                break;
        }
    }


    public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
        if (isWordSeparator(primaryCode)) {
            // Handle separator
            if (mComposing.length() > 0) {
                commitTyped(getCurrentInputConnection());
            }
            sendKey(primaryCode);
            updateShiftKeyState(getCurrentInputEditorInfo());
        } else if (primaryCode == Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE) {
            handleBackspace();
        } else if (primaryCode == Keyboard.KEYCODE_SHIFT) {
            handleShift();
        } else if (primaryCode == Keyboard.KEYCODE_CANCEL) {
            handleClose();
            return;
        } else if (primaryCode == LatinKeyboardView.KEYCODE_OPTIONS) {
            // Show a menu or somethin'
        } else if (primaryCode == Keyboard.KEYCODE_MODE_CHANGE
                && mInputView != null) {
            Keyboard current = mInputView.getKeyboard();
            if (current == mSymbolsKeyboard || current == mSymbolsShiftedKeyboard) {
                current = mQwertyKeyboard;
            } else {
                current = mSymbolsKeyboard;
            }
            mInputView.setKeyboard(current);
            if (current == mSymbolsKeyboard) {
                current.setShifted(false);
            }
        } else {
            handleCharacter(primaryCode, keyCodes);
        }
    }

    public void onText(CharSequence text) {
        InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
        if (ic == null) return;
        ic.beginBatchEdit();
        if (mComposing.length() > 0) {
            commitTyped(ic);
        }
        ic.commitText(text, 0);
        ic.endBatchEdit();
        updateShiftKeyState(getCurrentInputEditorInfo());
    }

    private void updateCandidates() {
        if (!mCompletionOn) {
            if (mComposing.length() > 0) {
                ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add(mComposing.toString());
                setSuggestions(list, true, true);
            } else {
                setSuggestions(null, false, false);
            }
        }
    }

    public void setSuggestions(List<String> suggestions, boolean completions,
            boolean typedWordValid) {
        if (suggestions != null && suggestions.size() > 0) {
            setCandidatesViewShown(true);
        } else if (isExtractViewShown()) {
            setCandidatesViewShown(true);
        }
        if (mCandidateView != null) {
            mCandidateView.setSuggestions(suggestions, completions, typedWordValid);
        }
    }

    private void handleBackspace() {
        final int length = mComposing.length();
        if (length > 1) {
            mComposing.delete(length - 1, length);
            getCurrentInputConnection().setComposingText(mComposing, 1);
            updateCandidates();
        } else if (length > 0) {
            mComposing.setLength(0);
            getCurrentInputConnection().commitText("", 0);
            updateCandidates();
        } else {
            keyDownUp(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL);
        }
        updateShiftKeyState(getCurrentInputEditorInfo());
    }

    private void handleShift() {
        if (mInputView == null) {
            return;
        }

        Keyboard currentKeyboard = mInputView.getKeyboard();
        if (mQwertyKeyboard == currentKeyboard) {
            // Alphabet keyboard
            checkToggleCapsLock();
            mInputView.setShifted(mCapsLock || !mInputView.isShifted());
        } else if (currentKeyboard == mSymbolsKeyboard) {
            mSymbolsKeyboard.setShifted(true);
            mInputView.setKeyboard(mSymbolsShiftedKeyboard);
            mSymbolsShiftedKeyboard.setShifted(true);
        } else if (currentKeyboard == mSymbolsShiftedKeyboard) {
            mSymbolsShiftedKeyboard.setShifted(false);
            mInputView.setKeyboard(mSymbolsKeyboard);
            mSymbolsKeyboard.setShifted(false);
        }
    }

    private void handleCharacter(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
        if (isInputViewShown()) {
            if (mInputView.isShifted()) {
                primaryCode = Character.toUpperCase(primaryCode);
            }
        }
        if (isAlphabet(primaryCode) && mPredictionOn) {
            mComposing.append((char) primaryCode);
            getCurrentInputConnection().setComposingText(mComposing, 1);
            updateShiftKeyState(getCurrentInputEditorInfo());
            updateCandidates();
        } else {
            getCurrentInputConnection().commitText(
                    String.valueOf((char) primaryCode), 1);
        }
    }

    private void handleClose() {
        commitTyped(getCurrentInputConnection());
        requestHideSelf(0);
        mInputView.closing();
    }

    private void checkToggleCapsLock() {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (mLastShiftTime + 800 > now) {
            mCapsLock = !mCapsLock;
            mLastShiftTime = 0;
        } else {
            mLastShiftTime = now;
        }
    }

    private String getWordSeparators() {
        return mWordSeparators;
    }

    public boolean isWordSeparator(int code) {
        String separators = getWordSeparators();
        return separators.contains(String.valueOf((char)code));
    }

    public void pickDefaultCandidate() {
        pickSuggestionManually(0);
    }

    public void pickSuggestionManually(int index) {
        if (mCompletionOn && mCompletions != null && index >= 0
                && index < mCompletions.length) {
            CompletionInfo ci = mCompletions[index];
            getCurrentInputConnection().commitCompletion(ci);
            if (mCandidateView != null) {
                mCandidateView.clear();
            }
            updateShiftKeyState(getCurrentInputEditorInfo());
        } else if (mComposing.length() > 0) {

            commitTyped(getCurrentInputConnection());
        }
    }

    public void swipeRight() {
        if (mCompletionOn) {
            pickDefaultCandidate();
        }
    }

    public void swipeLeft() {
        handleBackspace();
    }

    public void swipeDown() {
        handleClose();
    }

    public void swipeUp() {
    }

    public void onPress(int primaryCode) {
    }

    public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {
    }
}
```

And symbols.xml file :

```
   <Key android:codes="-3" android:keyIcon="@drawable/sym_keyboard_done" android:keyWidth="20%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="left" />
```

When I click `Done` key also I didn't go to `OnEditorActionListener` method. Please help me

Please help me this:

---

I have tried like this : But not proper solution. Anyhow I want to take actionId , according to actionId i want put switch statement & want to know why it didn't take actionId when we use other than the android keyboard

```
  txtQty.setOnEditorActionListener( new OnEditorActionListener() {
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

         if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){ } .....
```

Comment: Please anybody help me.I couldn't continue my rest of the part ...please

Comment: According to your description, this EditText code works or doesn't work depending on the keyboard. Therefore, the problem is in your soft keyboard code, not this EditText code. Please show the keyboard code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this for adding Listener :

```
    msg_title_text.setOnEditorActionListener(new DoneOnEditorActionListener());
```

Created a class :

```
    class DoneOnEditorActionListener implements OnEditorActionListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            Log.v("*****************************", "Clicke da machan");
            // Do your Stuffs
            return true;    
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Working fine. i used `if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){` this

Comment: I used both                                                          << if(actionId == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) >>                                            In my android 2.3 actionId is "6" (EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) but in my Android 4.3 it returns "66" (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)

Answer (score 3):

if you wanna got the actionid
try this way:

in my project
i change the edittext's properties like that

```
input type  -----  text
ime options -----  actionDone
```

and in java file:

> ```
>   etSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSearch);
>   etSearch.setOnEditorActionListener(mEditorActionListener);
> ```

```
private OnEditorActionListener mEditorActionListener = new OnEditorActionListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                       //do something
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

in this way could got the actionid = 6;

Comment: Thanks - just to add on that the DONE button is not similar to the RETURN button. To ensure that the softkeyboard actually shows the DONE button, set this in the xml by android:imeOptions="actionDone"